Make pyinstaller app open in separate non-terminal cli
I made a chatbot program in python, converted it to an EXE file, and the CLI opens in a terminal window. Is there a way to make it open in a custom CLI instead of a terminal window?
The python EXE opens in Powershell,and I want to find a way to make it run in another CLI as a non-terminal window.
I haven't tried anything yet, and need advice.

This has nothing to do with Python, it is a setting on your system. Also, what do you mean by "custom CLI"?

I mean the EXE opens in a Terminal tab, and I want it to be a separate window, with a window title, icon, etc. I don't like it opening in a console window

You are talking about a GUI application, so you would need to use a framework like tkinter etc., to do what you want. The default for a Python program is a console application type.

It doesn't have any GUI. The chatbot is entirely text-based, and opens in command prompt

if you want that, you need to code that.

Then it is doing what you have told it to do. That is how console based applications work, they need a command prompt window in order to run.
